# How to correctly rewrite only mysite.com to www.mysite.com and nothing else?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

Here's the section from Web.config that redirects naked domain to www.

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear/>
    <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\."/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

**The problem** is it also adds 'www' in front of any other address, like:

- localhost:62083 -> www.localhost:62083
- static.mysite.com -> www.static.mysite.com
- mysite.hostcompany.com -> www.mysite.hostcompany.com

I need it to redirect ONLY mysite.com and nothing else. How to fix the rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're over-thinking it. I can't test it, but the simplest way seems to be changing your condition to *just* match the name you want re-written.

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="false" pattern="^mysite.com$"/>`?
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="false" pattern="^mysite.com$"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `pattern` is a regular expression, you could use

```
^[^\.]\.[^\.]$
```

To only redirect on requests without subdomains (contains exactly one dot)

- Advantage: independent from domain name
- Disadvantage: Does not work for www.mysection.company.com